# Making a button move on refresh

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hello im trying to make a button move in php and looking for tips from j query guys to just in case its easier to do in j query. I have worked out if i put left right and center  ( the words ) in a array then pick one at random and print it out in side a div tag then put a button in the div tag the div should be arranged some times right , left , center which would make the button move ? here is my code

```
<?php
$Keywordarray = new array(3);  
$Keywordarray[0] = "left";  
$Keywordarray[1] = "right";  
$Keywordarray[2] = "center";  

$rand_key = array_rand($Keywordarray);


?>

<div align="<?php echo $rand_key ; ?>">

  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

But im getting a white page ?? I wanna try and move the button to stop macroing but only left right and center

I also have tryied this

```
<?php
$numbers = range(left, right , center);
shuffle($numbers);
foreach ($numbers as $number) {

}


?>

<div align="<?php echo $number ; ?>">

  <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>
```

Which the page appears but button does not move ?

Found some java script that works now

```
<HEAD>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">

<!-- This script and many more are available free online at -->
<!-- The JavaScript Source!! http://javascript.internet.com -->

<!-- Begin
var flag = 1;
function t() {
if(flag == 1) {
Y.style.top = "75px";
Y.style.left = "700px";
}
if(flag == 2) {
Y.style.top = "115px";
Y.style.left = "100px";
}
if(flag == 3) {
Y.style.top = "300px";
Y.style.left = "350px";
}
flag = flag + 1;
if(flag == 4) {
flag = 1;
}
}
function al() {
alert("Correct!");
}
// End -->
</script>

</HEAD>

<!-- STEP TWO: Copy this code into the BODY of your HTML document -->

<BODY>

<center>

</center>


</DIV>
<DIV ID="Y" STYLE="position:absolute; left:300px; top:300px; width:50px;
height:50px;">
<form>
<input type=button value="YES" onClick="t()">
</form>
</DIV>
```

Comment: Did you mean `$Keywordarray` instead of `$your_array`?

Comment: still does not work will edit top code

Comment: Look at the source in your browser (right click on the page > view source). What do you see there?

Comment: There is no source http://pokemontoxic.net/new_rpg/nickymove.php check if you don't believe me just a white page with no source i have html tags and body tags etc but they ent even showing

Comment: The `body tags etc` is important. I can't see anything, because it returns me status 500.

Comment: If i use the second code in my first post the page loads. but code does not work e.g the button does not move. But if i use the first code i get a white page

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$rand_key = $Keywordarray[array_rand($Keywordarray)];
```

You shoud first check the manual :)
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php
array-rand returns the key.

Comment: a white page might mean a php error, do you have error reporting on?

Comment: Yep i use ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);   to set it on and still white page ...

Comment: try $Keywordarray = new array();

Comment: can you post a link to the php file, or include it here to see exactly what it is there?

Comment: lol, you have session_start after html output, RULE: no html output before session_start, not even a space

Comment: still does not work with it at the top of the page be for everything

Comment: ive found some java script 2 do the job now